# Cannot type full pinyin character for Chinese for PinYIn input method in 14.04

Tags: chinese, pinyin

I am trying to input Chinese by PinYin method. However, when I tried to type 'deng' pinyin. It only allows me to type 'de' and then will saparate my input to de neng and another [deng] besides. What I want is the output of [deng]. I see [deng] is bracketed. And I wonder whether there  exist some method to let me select the 'deng' but not 'de neng'.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: same here, ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Google is your friend ! http://www.pinyinjoe.com/faq/ubuntu-1404-chinese-ime-problems-faq.htm

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450536/ suggest to simply use `ibus-daemon -drx`